# ant avoid rerunning a task

Tags: ant

i have a data generation task. Each task takes anywhere from 5 secs to 20 mins. There are over 2k tasks which depend on each other. To manage these takes I typically use GNUMake. But, I would like to give ant a try since its more compatible on windows.

How can I avoid re-running a task if its already done with ant? In GnuMake i do something like this:

```
taskA:
  touch $@
```

If I rerun taskA it won't run because its completed there is a target file. How can I achieve this in ant?

Comment: Hare you observed that it is rerunning the tasks? Can please you show some sample build script to reproduce the same?

Comment: Take a look at the [`<uptodate>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html). In particular, look at the example with: `<target name="xmlBuild" depends="chkXmlBuild" unless="xmlBuild.notRequired">`.